# Как реализовать многопоточность для python?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт по парсингу сайтов, сам скрипт работает хорошо, но медленно. Я рассматривал вариант пустить скрипт в несколько потоков, но ничего не получилось. Использовал threading. Есть нюанс - сайты обрабатываются разное время. Помогите разобраться как прикрутить многопоточность в моём случае.
python3

Пример скрипта

```
def pars(url):
    parsing
for i in range(10000):
    url = urls[i]
    pars(url)
```

Comment: Как самый простой вариант, можете просто вручную или программно запускать несколько копий скрипта с разными параметрами для обработки разных частей цикла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно так с использованием `multiprocessing`

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def pars(arg):
    print(arg)
  
def main():
    links = list(range(1, 10000))
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.map(pars, links)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: а как мне регулировать количество задействованных потоков?

Comment: @boris mp.cpu_count() выдает само. Можете туда пихать другое количество, например 2 , но не больше чем кол-во ядер*2

Comment: Ещё проблема. выходные данные должны быть - (1,2,3,4,5)
Но при использовании данного варианта вывод состоит примерно из - (1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,5)
Но может быть я не правильно его использую

Comment: @boris тогда думаю стоит уточнять все эти нюансы в вопросе, где не было ни слово про порядок и что в итоге кроме парсинга должно происходить

Comment: В main я генерирую ссылку и если после этого я его сразу отправляю в pars 

url = url
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    pool.map(pars, url)

то ссылка в pars передаётся по 1 символу - (Invalid URL 'h':, Invalid URL 't', Invalid URL 't' и т.д)
Но если сначала генерировать сразу весь список url и потом передавать его то выходит то что я описал выше.

Comment: Всё извиняюсь допустил косяк у себя, всё поправил, всё работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @boris пожалуйста

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123735/discussion-between-boris-and-vadim-sharoikin).